# return after if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, return

I saw an if statement with a return in a new I never saw before and wanted to ask what it does.

```
//class variable
private boolean isRunning = false;


public synchronized void start()
{
if(isRunning)return;
isRunning = true;
}
```

What is this code doing ?

Comment: Did you step through it in the debugger? Invoke it multiple times.

Comment: I just saw it in a video , the guy in the video tried to explain it ,but I didn't understand it right

Comment: @Aominè Ahh okay thanks mate I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Need to review the basics.

The `return` keyword is used to return from a method when its execution is complete. When a return statement is reached in a method, the program returns to the code that invoked it.

In your example, if the condition *isRunning* is true then the method will return at that point. When start() is called the first time *isRunning* is false so the if condition is false and execution continues.

You can rewrite your example like this with the same behavior:

```
public synchronized void start()
{ 
 if(!isRunning) {
     isRunning = true;
 } // else already running
}
```